# access - select representative sample data from live database

Tags: ms-access, sampling

We are regularly running controls of employees (based on employee_id) doing different types of transactions (based on transaction_id). To do so we are extracting a sample of live production data (sized by the Loi de Poisson).

The question is:
How can I make sure that every type of transaction is part of the sample, and that each employee is also being controlled in the sample, knowing that there is not always a combination of both.

For example, this is my live data (of course, mine is much larger).

```
Transaction_id Employee_id
100 123456
100 234567
101 123456
203 234567
203 345678
301 234567
```

I must make sure that in my sample, all transaction_id is selected at least once (100, 101, 203 and 301). I must also make sure that all my employees are selected at least once (123456, 234567, 345678). So the sample should be

```
301, 234567 -> only possibility
203, 345678 -> only possibility because if I select the other employee_id 234567, then employee_id 345678 will never be controlled
101, 123456 -> only possibility
100, 123456 or 234567
```

How would you advise I write the SQL statements to ensure that the sample data contains at least one occurrence of each transaction_id and at least one occurrence of employee_id ?

Comment: I would suggest fixing the random sample by picking a random row with each value. One E for each T and one T for each E. Then pick as many other rows as you need.

Comment: This will result in max(E,T) to E+T rows.

Comment: Random sampling is not something you should do using SQL in Access, especially not if you want to use criteria based on your previous rows. Asking for us to code a complex VBA example without showing an attempt we can fix is too broad for this site.

Comment: Please forgive me if you think that my problem is too complex to be addressed here. I was just asking to see if I had missed an obvious solution to my problem. I wasn't requesting a complex VBA code from this site :-)